# OSMnx Custom Filter - get all types of roads

Tags: openstreetmap, geocode, osmnx

I need to get all existing OSM types of roads from the area, and I'm searching for a simple way of doing this rather than specifying each type with "|"

I've tried to write something like this:

```
place_name = "Moscow"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type="all", custom_filter="%s")
```

or just

```
place_name = "Moscow"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type="all", custom_filter="highway")
```

However, in the first one I've received an error while the second one did not return all existing OSM values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devil's in the details: it depends on what you mean by "all roads." If the OSMnx "all_private" `network_type` is really not permissive enough for your needs, you can always just pass in a `custom_filter` that just retrieves everything tagged "highway". Refer to the OSMnx [docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/) and Overpass QL [wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL) for usage details.

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True

# get everything matching the built-in all_private filter
place_name = "Moscow"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type="all_private")
len(G)  # returns 457542

# get everything on OSM tagged "highway"
cf = '["highway"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, custom_filter=cf)
len(G)  # returns 459678
```